# Как получить набор уникальных индексов из индексов двух фреймов?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть `df1` и `df2`. У `df1` индексы `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`, у `df2` - индексы `1,2,3,8`.

Как из двух наборов индексов получить один, который включает в себя как индексы первого датафрейма, так и второго без дубликатов? Т.е., `df0` с индексами `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8`?

Пробовала так:

```
df0 = pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=['First', 'Second'], sort=False)
df0.groupby('Index').sum()
```

Здесь я использовала `sum()`, но по сути не имеет значение какую функцию использовать, так как в дальнейшем будут использованы только индексы. Но почему-то этот способ не работает. У меня сокращается общий набор индексов.

[Пример данных](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RPL7m6dNZFXm_ikEdi13JWfQWDwufw8sCV5tt5Vffkc/edit#gid=0).

Comment: Без небольшого воспроизводимого  примера входных данных и примера результата, который вы хотите получить не совсем понятно что именно вы пытаетесь сделать. Объединять можно горизонтально или вертикально, по индексу или полю или по нескольким полям...

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вам, все-таки нужно. Если нужен только список уникальных индексов, то и работайте с индексами как со списками. Если нет, тогда поясните, что делать со значениями с одинаковыми индексами в разных df.

Comment: @strawdog мне нужен только список уникальных индексов и все

Comment: @MaxU  так я же привела минимальный пример. И написала, что мне важен толко список индексов.

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, ну тогда [вот вам ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1280590/211923) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы найти отличия в значениях индексов двух фреймов можно воспользоваться методом [pd.Index.difference()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
In [33]: df1.index.difference(df2.index)
Out[33]:
Index(['Инвестиционные проекты, реализация которых обуславливается схемами и программами перспективного развития электроэнергетики, всего',
       'Москва',
       'Покупка земельных участков для целей реализации инвестиционных проектов, всего',
       'Прочее новое строительство объектов электросетевого хозяйства, всего',
       'Прочие инвестиционные проекты, всего',
       'Технологическое присоединение льготной категории потребителей (мощностью до 15 кВт)',
       'Технологическое присоединение энергопринимающих устройств потребителей максимальной мощностью до 15 кВт включительно, всего',
       'Технологическое присоединение энергопринимающих устройств потребителей, всего, в том числе:',
       'Технологическое присоединение, всего, в том числе:'],
      dtype='object')

In [34]: df2.index.difference(df1.index)
Out[34]: Index(['Index', 'Моя строка'], dtype='object')
```

или так чтобы найти все значения, которые не встречаются в обоих индексах:

```
In [35]: df1.index.union(df2.index).difference(df1.index.intersection(df2.index))
Out[35]:
Index(['Index',
       'Инвестиционные проекты, реализация которых обуславливается схемами и программами перспективного развития электроэнергетики, всего',
       'Москва', 'Моя строка',
       'Покупка земельных участков для целей реализации инвестиционных проектов, всего',
       'Прочее новое строительство объектов электросетевого хозяйства, всего',
       'Прочие инвестиционные проекты, всего',
       'Технологическое присоединение льготной категории потребителей (мощностью до 15 кВт)',
       'Технологическое присоединение энергопринимающих устройств потребителей максимальной мощностью до 15 кВт включительно, всего',
       'Технологическое присоединение энергопринимающих устройств потребителей, всего, в том числе:',
       'Технологическое присоединение, всего, в том числе:'],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 5):

решение для приведенного в вопросе примера данных:

```
In [8]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])

In [9]: df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3,8])

In [10]: df0_index = df1.index.union(df2.index)

In [11]: df0_index
Out[11]: Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: давайте, я все же приведу реальный пример, а то на моих данных не отрабатывает . как надо. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RPL7m6dNZFXm_ikEdi13JWfQWDwufw8sCV5tt5Vffkc/edit#gid=0

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, что значит не отрабатывает? И как надо? ;)

Comment: Ну в одном , дата фрейме у меня 110 строк, в другом - 102(101 как у первого, а одна отличается), юнион по идеи должен вернуть 111, а он возвращает 109.

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova, если возвращает 109, значит так и есть. Строковые значения сравниваются с учетом пробелов (в начале/ в конце, которых вы можете не заметить),  регистра (большая/маленькая буква) и т.д.